# subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 127 with weird sEDUsEDUsEDU.. message

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I was trying to install basic application on Ubuntu 18.04 system name cowsay.
Till now everything was working fine. 
Now, I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

and it gives me a long error as

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  filters cowsay-off
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cowsay
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 89.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
/usr/bin/dpkg-split: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg-split: sEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDU: 
File name too long
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cowsay_3.03+dfsg2-4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cowsay_3.03+dfsg2-4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried all possible stuffs like

1) Restarting my PC

2) `sudo apt-get autoclean`

3) `sudo apt-get -f install`

4) `sudo apt-get autoremove`

5) `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade`

6) `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Still the error was as it is

Then I went to the directory of `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

I think that there is an error in the package *dpkg* itself. The *deb* files were downloaded while performing install but dpkg somehow cannot install it. 
I tried the command

```
dpkg -i *<package name>*
```

But it gives the same error.

Can someone please tell me the possible solution to this problem? I am unable to install any pacakges.

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but I lately have had random source code files replaced with unreadable stuff that contains 'sEDUsEDUsEDU' in there. I think it might be a hard-disk problem.